# Assign an appropriate Grammatical function & Semantic Role to each phrase:

Tags: semantics

1. *John's mother sent a letter to Mary.*
2. *We placed the cheese in the freezer.*
3. *John made a doll for his daughter.*
4. *Mary received an award from the department.*
5. *Alan gave the book to the students.*

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please notice that the site is not for solving your homework assignment without your own effort. Read this http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask first and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: True. However, I think it would be a good test for people answering questions here. Note that this has several kinds of sentence and there are a number of grammatical functions and semantic roles displayed. My guess is that a lot of people couldn't do it.

Comment: What a quandary! @JohnLawler has thrown down the gauntlet, but we can't do Talha Usman's homework for him.

Comment: I did it!  It should be okay to do it if we don't say what the answer is, right?

Comment: I did it too, and I suspect my answers will resemble Greg's.

Comment: To be honest, I doubt that such school test questions give any insight into grammar. The formulation of the question is pitiful. There are no phrases but sentences. What is the "grammatical function" of a sentence?? In my opinion a non-sensical question. And "semantic role of a sentence??

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article to help OP with his second question, but I've seen different lists:

> **Thematic relation** [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation)]
>
> (This article does not cite any references or sources. Please help
>   improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources.
>   Unsourced material may be challenged and removed. (May 2014) )
>
> In a number of theories of linguistics, *thematic relations* is a term
>   used to express the role that a noun phrase plays with respect to the
>   action or state described by a sentence's verb. For example, in the
>   sentence "Susan ate an apple", Susan is the doer of the eating, so she
>   is an agent; the apple is the item that is eaten, so it is a patient.
>   While most modern linguistic theories make reference to such relations
>   in one form or another, the general term, as well as the terms for
>   specific relations, varies; 'participant role', 'semantic role', and
>   'deep case' have been used analogously to 'thematic relation'.
>
> **Major thematic relations**
>
> **Agent**: deliberately performs the action (e.g., *Bill* ate his soup quietly.).
>
> **Experiencer**: the entity that receives sensory or emotional input (e.g. *Susan* heard the song. I cried.).
>
> **Stimulus**: Entity that prompts sensory or emotional feeling - not deliberately (e.g. Kim detests *sprouts*).
>
> **Theme**: undergoes the action but does not change its state (e.g., We believe in one *God*. I have *two children*. I put *the book* on the
>   table. He gave *the gun* to the police officer.) (Sometimes used
>   interchangeably with patient.)
>
> **Patient**: undergoes the action and changes its state (e.g., The falling rocks crushed *the car*.). (Sometimes used interchangeably with
>   theme.)
>
> **Instrument**: used to carry out the action (e.g., Jamie cut the ribbon *with a pair of scissors*.).
>
> **Force or Natural Cause**: mindlessly performs the action (e.g., *An avalanche* destroyed the ancient temple.).
>
> **Location**: where the action occurs (e.g., Johnny and Linda played carelessly *in the park*. I'll be *at Julie's house* studying for my
>   test.).
>
> **Direction or Goal**: where the action is directed towards (e.g., The caravan continued on *toward the distant oasis*. He walked *to school*.).
>
> **Recipient**: a special kind of goal associated with verbs expressing a change in ownership, possession. (E.g., I sent *John* the letter. He
>   gave the book *to her*.)
>
> **Source or Origin**: where the action originated (e.g., The rocket was launched *from Central Command*. She walked *away from him*.).
>
> **Time**: the time at which the action occurs (e.g., The rocket was launched *yesterday*.).
>
> **Beneficiary**: the entity for whose benefit the action occurs (e.g.. I baked *Reggie* a cake. He built a car *for me*. I fight *for the king*.).
>
> **Manner**: the way in which an action is carried out (e.g., *With great urgency*, Tabitha phoned 911.).
>
> **Purpose**: the reason for which an action is performed (e.g., Tabitha phoned 911 right away *in order to get some help*.).
>
> **Cause**: what caused the action to occur in the first place; not for what, rather because of what (e.g., *Because Clyde was hungry*, he ate
>   the cake.).
>
> *There are no clear boundaries between these relations. For example, in
>   "the hammer broke the window", some linguists treat hammer as an
>   agent, some others as instrument, while some others treat it as a
>   special role different from these.*

Comment: I'd prefer if you'd posted a link to this article as a comment, rather than as a proper answer, in order to not encourage further do-my-homework-for-me questions.

Comment: But I think it's important enough to post in its own right. I've been waiting for an opportunity. See Greg Lee's comment. I haven't spelled out the answer. And I always try to observe the spirit of any law.

Comment: Fair enough.  I trust your judgement.

Comment: **Agent**: deliberately performs the action -- not right.  Consider "Bill accidentally ate his soup quietly."

Comment: You may certainly find the above needs amending. But please come up with a more sensible example. (An accidental deed by a sentient being.)

Comment: That's **Volitional Agent**. As you say, there are other lists. I rather like [the semantics given by Frawley for Entities (aka "nouns")](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/frawleyentities.pdf).

Comment: Terminology, as usual, is not standardised. From [OCW - Universitat de Barcelona_filologia-anglesa](http://ocw.ub.edu/filologia-anglesa/gramatica-descriptiva-de-langles-ii/course_files/Clause_Structure/GDII_Clause_Structure_08-09_Semantic_Roles_.pdf):  • AGENT: animate **and** volitional causer [broader sense] or initiator of any action/event.
_John_ killed the dog [before it could kill the sheep].
• CAUSER: inanimate or non-volitional entity which is directly involved in the causation of an event.
_The rain_ ruined the crop. / [_John_ killed the dog, though he wasn't even aware he'd hit it.]